# Get name of image published from Openshift to artifactory

Tags: openshift, artifactory, docker-registry

In my BuildConfig I have specified output to:

`kind: DockerImage`

`name: my-artifactory-repo/image-name:latest`

When I look inside my-artifactory-repo/image-name:latest there are a lot of different images named with some sha256 functions. Is there some way in Openshift to get this sha256-name of the image that is uploaded to artifactory?

I've tried looking inside build details with no luck.

Comment: Why would you want an individual sha 256 layer in openshift? This is only one layer of the image.

Answer (score 2):

There is a variety of ways to get this into Openshift.

Using pure Openshift only the easiest would be an ImageStream. You could then upload the entire docker image into the Openshift ImageStream not just one sha256 layer.

Goto Build -> Image Stream then click New Image Stream

[image]

Specify the name and namespace of this image.

[image]

Click create.

Change your Build config to this name now to deploy directly into an Openshift image stream.

We also support deploying Artifactory into Openshift itself through our Certified Operator [here](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/operators/detail/5e98733e3f398525a0ceafd4).